# Init Function doesn't run in release mode but runs in debug mode

Tags: flutter

```dart
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    moveNext();
    _initializeFirebase();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    if (currentPage.length == 1) {
      return (await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Are you sure?'),
              content: Text('Do you want to exit'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  child: Text('No'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                  child: Text('Yes'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )) ??
          false;
    } else {
      Navigation.pop(context);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainApp()));
      return false;
    }
  }

  void moveNext() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!noMove) {
      bool connected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
      bool? logIn = true;
      if (forceLogOut) {
        logIn = false;
      } else {
        if (auth.currentUser != null) {
          logIn = true;
        } else {
          logIn = prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn");
        }
      }


      if (connected) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
          setState(() {
            internetConnected = true;
          });
          if (!forceHomeScreen) {
            if (logIn != null) {
              if (logIn) {
                Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () async {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigation.pushReplace(context, homePage);
                    setState(() {});
                  });
                });
                await AppAPI().getCurrentUser();
                await AppAPI().getData();
                setState(() {});
              } else {
                Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigation.pushReplace(context, Welcome());
                    forceLogOut = false;
                  });
                });
              }
            } else {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
                setState(() {
                  forceLogOut = false;
                  Navigation.pushReplace(context, Welcome());
                  setState(() {});
                });
              });
            }
          } else {
            setState(() {
              Navigation.pushReplace(context, homePage);
              setState(() {});
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          setState(() {
            internetConnected = false;
            Navigation.pushReplace(context, NoInternet());
            setState(() {});
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: currentPage.last));
  }
}
```

So, there's this page with a cool loading screen animation. But here's the thing: when you're testing it in debug mode, everything works fine. The 'init' function does its job and smoothly moves you to the next page. But when you switch to release mode, moveNext() function just doesn't work

I have seen some other posts on this and one i could find were not having this line "" in your Main Manifest but i already have it

MANIFEST :

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


    <application
        android:label="ThePhotographers"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me the line you already have in the manifest file. This is my suggestions but please make sure that you have internet permission in your Android manifest file and there may be more permission you need to specify depending upon the elements you are using. And you can check if your init function is not working or the custom function ,just show a toast in the init function in that way we can make sure that where is actually the problem in init() or your custom fn.

Comment: i have added the manifest in the question and i did the toast method you told and i found out it fails exactly at `if (auth.currentUser != null) {` because in the if and else i have a toast and none of them played.